# How to keep updated react context value inside a callback in a custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have a userContext wrapped my app, I have a custom hook useAnalytics used to send analytics events and I have a Login component which performs the log in and changes the user value in the context and send an event.

My problem is when I do a setUser inside my Login component the updating user data is not reflected  in useAnalytics hook which it sends always the user data in every event

Here a sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/romantic-perlman-wzxti?file=/src/Login.js
You can open the console and see the results after clicking SEND

I know this is probably an anti-pattern but it would be good to know why I get this behavior

Thanks!

Comment: As I understand the issue is that on the first click it sends an empty object instead of `{user: "pippo"}`, am I right?

Comment: @BesoKakulia yes! you are right! :)

Comment: the solutions below should work, your problem is that you send analytics before the state is updated, as updating state in react is an asynchronous operation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that all set states are async, while the sending of the event is in sync. So you dispatch the change, send the analytic and after a timeout, the state is updated.
There are 2 main ways to fix this.

1. Set a timeout to wait for react to update the state and push the analytic after  the state is updated:

```
setUser({ type: "login", data: { user: "pippo" } });
setTimeout(sendEvent, 16);
```

2. Send the analytic with a middleware:

Add a middleware to intercept all reducer changes and push those to the analytic without the hook itself. This will guarantee that you get all changes that you need to track by checking for the `action.type` and sending the new data from action.payload.

Comment: Hi! While I'm with the second solution... why the magic number 16 in `setTimeout`? @Domino987

Comment: That's the time frame for react updates. Each frame had a maximum of 16ms .

Comment: I dint' know that, can you provide documentation @Domino987 ?

Comment: I heard a talk about the fiber internals a year back and here is an article covering it: https://blog.logrocket.com/deep-dive-into-react-fiber-internals/